# Is is possible to populate a SharePoint list from an Excel sheet?

Tags: sharepoint, list

So you can export a list to a spread sheet, but can you do the opposite?  Preferably from an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go the the Create menu in sharepoint and upder Custom Lists, click Import Spreadsheet.  Type the name of the list, browse to the spreadsheet and click Import.

You can also sync your spreadsheet and list on a continual basis by making a list on your spreadsheet and then publishing that to sharepoint.

1. Open your sheet
2. Select your data
3. Click Crtl+l
4. Click ok
5. Right click list
6. Publish list
7. type name of sharepoint site
8. name of sharepoint list
9. click Finish

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it from Excel 2003 :( bit is bit limiting. There is [a workaround](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462636(office.11).aspx) to do the same from Excel 2007...

But, to achieve best results you should use Access 2007 because it provides you with everything you need. It allows you to do the same you can as from the web interface.